# Individual files making program erratic performance

Tags: excel, vba

I am making individual daily price data files for Tickers from Daily Price Data file. Program code appended below is not working properly. Sometimes it runs and makes 60 files and then fails to save a file and subsequently it fails to paste the desired range data though it creates the files. Other times it may fail to save even after 5th file or may be after 30th file. I even introduced pause time .

```
     Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:03 AM#)
```

But it does not solve the problem. Program fails on the following code line arbitrarily.

```
 .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\kakka\Desktop\SymbolData\" & cell & "-v1.xls", FileFormat:=56
```

Program code is appended below.

```
Sub number()

    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim cell, rng As Range
    Dim stRw As Long
    Set rng = Range("A2:A72")
    stRw = 2
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value <> cell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then

        Set wbI = ActiveWorkbook
        Set wsI = wbI.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set wbO = Workbooks.Add

            With wbO
                 Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")
                 .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\kakka\Desktop\SymbolData\" & cell & "-v1.xls", FileFormat:=56
                 wsI.Range("A1:H1").Copy
                 wsO.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                 wsI.Rows(stRw & ":" & cell.Row).Copy
                 wsO.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                .Close SaveChanges:=True
                stRw = cell.Row + 1
            End With
        Set wbI = Nothing
        Set wsI = Nothing
        Set wbO = Nothing
        Set wsO = Nothing



        End If
    Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:03 AM#)
    Next cell


End Sub
```

[image: Data File Snapshot]

[image: Unsaved File Snapshot]

[image: Saved File Snapshot]
Request help in resolving this issue.

Comment: your `cell` variable is declared as a variant. Firstly, are you sure it has a value set? and Seconly try using `.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\kakka\Desktop\SymbolData\" & cell.Value2 & "-v1.xls", FileFormat:=56`

Comment: What error do you get when it "fails on the following code line arbitrarily"?

Comment: `wsI.Range("A1:H1").Copy` is a huge waste of resources. Instead of copying the entire column, only copy the range with data in it. This may be causing an overload especially because there's a long loop. You can also make it more efficient by removing copy/paste technique and setting `range.value = range.value`, directly.

Comment: @Tom your suggestion to add Value2 after Cell  solves the problem. Please make it as an answer so that I may tick it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @skkakkar Glad it worked - added

Comment: @Comintern File opens up and I have to save manually. Problem stands solved by Tom's suggestion.

Comment: @Scott Holtzman I shall workout on your suggestion also and update later though problem stands resolved by Tom's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a range variant to concatenate your String FilePath

Use `cell.Value2` to concatenate the cell value with your String FilePath.

```
.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\kakka\Desktop\SymbolData\" & cell.Value2 & "-v1.xls", FileFormat:=56
```

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that writing `Dim cell` as `Dim cell as Range` would also solve the issue, because `.Value` is the default property of a range object. It's also a wiser solution because the code does not use a variant data type in an unnecessary way.